# MSSQL 2008 is claiming the firewall is blocking ports even from local machine

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I was just hoping to step through a couple queries to see how the temp tables are interacting and I'm getting this message.

> The windows firewall on this machine is currently blocking remote debugging.
>   Remote debugging requires that the debugging be allowed to receive information
>   from the network.Remote debugging also requires DCOM (TCP port 135) and 
>   IPSEC (UDP 4500/UDP500) be unblocked

Even when I walked over to the actual machine and tried running the debugger, I'm still getting the same message.  Am I missing something or does the debugger try to run remotely even from the local machine?  Since this was meant to be just a quick check, I don't need instructions on how to open up the firewall, just hoping there is a way to run the debugger locally instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think this article address your need...  it clearly states if you running it locally on the same box, no need to muck with the firewall.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646024.aspx

> There are no configuration requirements to run the Transact-SQL debugger when SQL Server Management Studio is running on the same computer as the instance of the SQL Server Database Engine. However, to run the Transact-SQL debugger when SQL Server Management Studio is running on a different computer from the instance of the Database Engine, you must enable program and port exceptions on both computers.

Comment: yeah, I didn't think there would be any requirements for running on the local machine since it shouldn't even be trying to jump outside of the firewall in the first place.  I'll go back and make sure I'm using "localhost" instead of the IP and see if that helps at all.

Comment: It should. If you use the local IP then to my knowledge it DOES Loop through the firewall on purpose ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  You might be running into permission problems on the local machine.  I ran the management studio application as administrator which did the trick for me!